# Flash - crossdomain.xml not working properly

Tags: xml, flash

I've uploaded a game to kongregate - the game features a "save to gallery" function which allows the user to save a screenshot to a gallery on my server.  However, I can't get the crossdomain.xml file set up properly to allow access from kongregate to my server.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="kongregate.com" secure="false"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="kongregate.com" headers="kongregate.com" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Sending code (from http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/dynamically-create-an-image-in-flash-and-save-it-to-the-desktop-or-server/ ):

```
function okFun(event:MouseEvent):void {
                var stgName = stgpopup.popupName.text;
                var img:BitmapSnapshot = new BitmapSnapshot(stage, stgName + ".png");
                img.saveOnServer("http://jalexygames.com/games/sp2h/upload.php", "http://jalexygames.com/games/sp2h/albums/Shop-Designs/");
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.jalexygames.com/games/sp2h/Shop-Designs/"), "_blank");
                stgpopup.visible = false;
            }
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly ? Users can't send images to your server ? Could you show us the code using to send the image to your server ? Could you provide us with a link of your game to try it online to see how it's working, it can help ? ...

Comment: Correct - the image is not being sent to the server.  I will add the send code to the original post.  The game is http://www.kongregate.com/games/JalexyGames/swords-and-potions-2-helper

Comment: played around with it and now Charles is reporting a successful post to `http://jalexygames.com/games/sp2h/upload.php?filename=test.png&destination=http://jalexygames.com/games/sp2h/albums/Shop-Designs/` which looks correct to me, but the image is still not being uploaded.

Comment: But I think that `destination` param should be a dir on your server and not an url ?!

Comment: Thank you!  That was indeed the problem.